# How to increase the number of days for logging for Spring Boot logback-spring.xml

Tags: spring-boot

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated!!

My SpringBoot application is logging only 1 day. I want it to log more than 30 days.

logback-spring.xml

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="ca.test.hub" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.cxf" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

application.yml:

```
logging:
```

file: logs/test.log
  pattern:
    console: "%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n"
    file: "%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n"
  level:
    root: INFO

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep log files for more than 30 days your best bet is not to use `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` ([documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FixedWindowRollingPolicy)), which is used if you only want to limit the amount of log files that are kept on the file system.

A better appender suited for your requirements would be `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy` which, as stated in the [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy),

> archive[s] files essentially by date but at the same time limit the size
>   of each log file

My suggested edit to your current `FILE` appender would be something like this

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

This `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy` stores files with the `fileNamePattern` `LOG_FILE-2019-05-02.0` (LOG_FILE would of course be the value for the `${LOG_FILE}` variable). This file will roll over every time it reaches a size larger that 10MB - and then a new file, `LOG_FILE-2019-05-02.1`, will be created and written to.

First log to be written after midnight would then create a new file, `LOG_FILE-2019-05-03.0`, and write to it. Log files older than 30 days will be deleted. Adjust the configuration to best suit your needs.

I'd recommend you read the [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy) for this appender to get a bit more details.